# ¿Cómo borrar una etiqueta tag en GIT?

Tags: git

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente en un repositorio local.

Cree un `tag` sobre una rama actual pero me olvidé de unir con un commit de un compañero, por lo que necesito saber es: ¿cómo se hace para eliminarlo localmente o es posible hacer que apunte a otro commit?, ¿en caso que se hubiese subido al servidor cómo sería?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No me parece que exista forma de mover un tag o de decirle que apunte a otro commit. En todo caso, si lo tienes localmente simplemente elimínalo y creas el correcto después de hacer el merge:

```
$ git tag --delete nombre-del-tag
$ git merge branch-de-tu-amigo
$ git tag nombre-del-tag
```

Si ya hiciste el `push` y mandaste el tag al origen entonces tienes que hacer:

```
$ git push --delete origin nombre-del-tag
```

Verifica que ya no exista haciendo un listado de los tags:

```
$ git tag --list
```